# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when using REST in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api

I am getting the following error when I run my Python REST API script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api_tufin_4.py", line 4, in <module>
    b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\base64.py", line 62, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am using the following code:

```
import requests, base64

usrPass = "user:pass"
b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass)
api_URL = 'api-url'
r=requests.post(api_URL, 
                headers={"Authorization": "Basic %s" % b64Val},
                data=payload)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64.b64encode` works on binary data (`bytes`), not text data (`str`).

Make your username/password a `bytes` literal and you're fine. If it's ASCII, the translation is trivial:

```
usrPass = "user:pass"
```

becomes:

```
usrPass = b"user:pass"
```

The leading `b` makes it [a `bytes` literal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).